# Shell command as a variable in Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

I have the following (very simplified) Makefile:

```
# Makefile

MAKESH=shell
USER=$($MAKESH logname)
```

which aims to store my login name in the `USER` variable as if the `$(shell logname)` command was invoked. However this doesn't happen. I suspect that it's due to the way `make` evaluates variables.

Does anyone have some more insight to this or a possible workaround i.e. explicitly tell `make` that `$MAKESH` is actually the `shell` command?

Thanks.

### Edit

Consider the following example:

```
#parent.mk

...
include child.mk
...

-------------------
#child.mk

export $(shell logname)/path1
export $(shell logname)/path2

-------------------
#bash_script.sh

...
source child.mk
...
```

(in this example, sourcing child.mk fails)

Essentially, what I wanted to do is to create a file that exports pathnames depending on the current user. The syntax should be valid both for makefiles and bash scripts, since it can be included/sourced from both places.

I also wanted to do subtle changes to these files, since they are part of a larger project and the interconnections are a bit confusing.

I have finally decided to go with this:

```sh
#parent.mk

...
export logname=$(shell logname)
include child.mk
...

-------------------
#child.mk

export $(logname)/path1
export $(logname)/path2

-------------------
#bash_script.sh

...
source child.mk
...
```

which is quite hacky, a tiny bit dangerous, but works. If you know a more elegant way/aprroach, let me know.

Finally, thank you for your solutions (and your warnings), which are valid for the pre-editted question.

Comment: Why would you want this? BTW it is not the `shell` command, but the `shell` *function*.

Comment: the variable USER will not be evaluated until it is used. If you want to get it evaluated immediately use the form `:=` for the assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MAKESH=shell
$(eval USER=$$($(MAKESH) logname))
$(info USER is $(USER))
```

Avoid if possible.

Comment: Both answers are the same, but this one also includes the very useful $(info) function.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax should be

```
USER = $(shell logname)
```

I don't know why you want to put "shell" in a variable and screw up the function syntax, but if you really insist, try this:

```
$(eval USER=$$($MAKESH logname))
```

The $(eval ...) function will just turn it into the first form above, though, so it's wasted effort. (Unless your really trying to do something trickier than your example suggests.)